# responsive absolute center within flexslider plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css, center, flexslider

I have installed [Flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) jquery plugin.
I have some images inside my slides and over each image I want to add some content which will be horizontally and vertically centered regardless screen sizes

I'm trying to use the **table-cell** technique  but it seems that is not working or maybe I'm not using it correctly.

Here's the markup:

```
<div id="slider" class="flexslider is-Table">
<ul class="slides">
    <li>
        <div class="Table-Cell">
            <div class="Center-Block">
                DUMMY CENTERED CONTENT
            </div>
        </div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1400x700" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1400x700" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/1400x700" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

and this is the CSS :

```
#slider {border:none;}
.is-Table {display:table;}

.Table-Cell {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 }

.Center-Block {
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
z-index:999999;
}
```

and here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dynamyc/ztXLA/6/)

What I want to do is centering the `DUMY CONTENT`  over the image horizontally and vertically without using fixed width and heights because I want it to be responsive.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that `display:table` is not ideal for this situation. It works best when you can pass a specific height to the table or it's container.

I don't know the type of content you're trying to center, but one solution that may work is to  position it absolutely in percentages.

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ztXLA/8/)**

HTML:

```
<div id="slider" class="flexslider is-Table">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <div class="centered">
                    DUMMY CENTERED CONTENT
            </div>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1400x700" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1400x700" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/1400x700" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slides > li {
    position: relative;
}
.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 30%;
}
```

Comment: The type of content is just some text with some borders eventually.Regarding to your answers this can work but is not responsive. Is there a better solution and responsive?

Comment: @agis, I'm confused. On my side this solution is responsive, it stays consistently centered regardless of window height and width. Is this not the case on your side?

Comment: I've tested it on js fiddle and if I resize the screen it doesn't stay centered regardless of window height and width